# How do I add to the html of a page from the codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to `POST` a PayPal or GoogleCheckout "buy now" button from the code behind.

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121196/939213) answer telling me to add to the current html page. But the code there doesn't work as is. The code there adds a `literal` with the following line:

```
__parent.AddControl( _lit );
```

Which obviously doesn't work as is.

How *can* it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**aspx**

```
<div runat="server" id="div"></div>
```

**codebhind**

```
  Literal ltr= new Literal();
  ltr.Text="mytext";
  div.Controls.Add(ltr);
```

Working fine for me